# Create a page with a quotation mark at the bottom-right corner

Tags: quoting, blank-page, page

I am trying to create a page, with a quotation in the bottom left corner of the page. This is my trial

```
\newpage\hbox{\epigraph{I recall seeing a package to make quotes}{Snowball}}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
```

It creates error when compiling. Also, it is not placed in the bottom left corner of the page.